# Were there any "good" Separatist military leaders?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-clone-wars, good-against-evil, morality

In *[Heroes on Both Sides](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Heroes_on_Both_Sides)* as well as other works, we see that there are "good" Separatist politicians who genuinely believe the Separatist cause will improves the lives of the general population and don't know of the Separatist military's war crimes and general evilness. However, most of the Separatist military leaders we see (Dooku, Grievous, Trench, Ventress, etc.) seem genuinely evil.

Do we ever see any genuinely good Separatist military leaders in any work from either continuity?

Military leaders who:

1. Are genuinely working for what they believe is better for everyone.
2. Don't commit war crimes.
3. Cause deaths but don't like killing.
4. Don't order unnecessary or unnecessarily cruel deaths.

Comment: Yes, all the dead ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not from anything we see or read in canon, onscreen or in legends.

In *the Clone Wars* cartoon (which is canon) the civilian leadership of the Separatists were sometimes good beings. Count Dooku was manipulating them, just as Palpatine was manipulating the Senate.

The military leadership however were all in cahoots with Count Dooku, and ranged from being self-serving and greedy (e.g., Watt Tambor), to lightsaber-wielding psychopaths who loved beheading people (General Grievous).

Many of them started committing atrocities once they began losing the war. Shu Mai, for example, ordered her army to poison the water on Felucia after she fled.

Admiral Trench is probably among the least morally-dubious of the Separatist military leaders. He though, was still complicit in hostage-taking, famine-inducing blockades, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is Meena Bonteri, and in a few "Clone Wars" episodes, peace talks are  mentioned or even in progress.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Meena Bonteri was a politician, not a military leader.

Comment: I suggest editing your answer to more directly address the question.

Answer (score -3):

Padme knew a Seperatist leader named Meena Bonteri. Clone forces killed her husband, but she still wanted peace. She advocated for peace negotiations with the Republic.

Comment: That is what the other answer says. Sadly, both your and the other answers lack any sources. Can you provide an episode number, the name of the book, or any source? _Where_ is Meena Bonteri featured? Can you also provide any quotes?